# Why can't I change items in a Python list using a step?

Tags: python

So I am still in the beginning stages of learning Python--and coding as a whole for that matter.

My question is why can I not change items in a Python list using a step, like this:

```
def myfunc2(string):
    new = list(string)
    new[0::2] = new[0::2].upper()
    new[1::2] = new[1::2].lower()

    return '' .join(new)

 myfunc2('HelloWorld')
```

I want to make every other letter upper and lower case, starting at index 0.

I had already seen a solution posted by another user, and although this other solution worked I had trouble understanding the code. So, in my curiosity I tried to work out the logic myself and came up with the above code.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new[0::2]` returns a list, which does not have an `upper` method . Same goes for `new[1::2]` and `lower`.

You can achieve your goal with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
def myfunc2(string):
    new = list(string)
    new[0::2] = map(str.upper, new[0::2])
    new[1::2] = map(str.lower, new[1::2])
    return '' .join(new)

print(myfunc2('HelloWorld'))
# HeLlOwOrLd
```

Comment: oh ok, list dont have a upper or lower method. That helps, so in the code you provided is the 'str' a local argument or is the whole string ' str.upper " the full method for maping new arguments to a list?

Comment: @MichaelPadilla Simply (but not 100% accurately) put, `str.upper` *references* the `upper` method every string object has. `map` is just responsible for calling that method on each string in the `new[0::2]` list.

Comment: Thank you sooo much, so further clarification then, so if i were trying to call a method for intergers to iterate across a list it would be int.round() for example ( if there are even that many methods for ints)

Comment: @MichaelPadilla That's correct. In theory, it would have been `int.round` (you want to *reference* the method, not *call* it). However, `int` objects do not have a `round` method. `round` is a global function (and it doesn't really make sense to round an integer anyway), so the `map` call would look something like `map(round, list_of_floats)`

Comment: Yeah, it was just an example to help me understand. Thank you so much this helped a lot in understanding what is actually happening.